# Polar co-ordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In double integration to switch to polar co-ordinates, we switch from $dxdy$ to $rdrd\theta$.
But in the solution for the problem below only $drd\theta$ is used instead of $rdrd\theta$.

I cannot understand why!

Problem: Express the double integral over the given region R as an iterated integral in polar coordinates:
The region lying inside the circle with center at the origin and radius 2. and to the left of the vertical line through(−1,0).

Solution:
$$\int\int_R drd\theta = \int_{\frac{2\pi}{3}}^{\frac{4\pi}{3}}\int_{-sec\theta}^{2}drd\theta$$

I understand the limits part which I got right.
But why is $drd\theta$ considered here and not $rdrd\theta$.Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was never a change of coordinates. The original integral was a $drd\theta$ integral over a region $R$ that you needed to iterate.

Comment: ohh...I get that!